# Copy Files from Windows to Windows Subsystem for Linux (WSL)

Tags: linux, windows, bash, windows-10, windows-subsystem-for-linux

I have enabled developer mode and installed `Bash on Ubuntu on Windows`.

My home directory can be found under `%localappdata%\Lxss\home\<ubuntu.username>\`, i have created a sub-directory called Pictures such that the full path should be

on windows: `C:\Users\<windows.username>\AppData\Local\lxss\home\<ubuntu.username>\Pictures`

on bash: `/home/<ubuntu.username>/Pictures`

if i create a file from bash using the command `touch hello.txt` i can freely see this file in the windows UI and copy it to my Desktop. However, if i create a new text file from the windows UI and save it in `C:\Users\<windows.username>\AppData\Local\lxss\home\<ubuntu.username>\Pictures`, even if i restart bash or windows, the file is not visible when i do `ls -l`.

Why can't bash see files created from the Windows side in it's own home directory?

**EDIT** Using `/mnt/c` is not a solution, i am trying to understand **why** it doesn't see those files and if there is a remedy to that so that it will be able to see UI created files, rather than trying to use the terminal to copy-paste or move files over.

Comment: Interesting!  My guess - and it *is* just a guess - is that the Linux subsystem keeps track of its own files and never looks to see if any others have been added.  That would sort of make sense, because otherwise it would be difficult to give the virtual file system UNIX semantics for things like deleting files and case sensitivity.  I suspect you'll find that if you create `hello.txt` and `HELLO.TXT` from Bash, one of the files will be under a different name when you look at it in Windows.

Comment: Stack Overflow is a site for programming and development questions. This question appears to be off-topic because it is not about programming or development. See [What topics can I ask about here](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) in the Help Center. Perhaps [Super User](http://superuser.com/) or [Unix & Linux Stack Exchange](http://unix.stackexchange.com/) would be a better place to ask. Also see [Where do I post questions about Dev Ops?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/134306)

Comment: As @HarryJohnston supposed, the names are different. Both long and short. But only in the case, even short ones (!)

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is related to the ask-ubuntu community.

Comment: @OmG Many questions do not belong strictly on one site. However, this is better suited to [su], since two different OSes are involved. (Or, strictly speaking, only Windows is involved.)

Comment: @jpaugh I know. But, this question is justified to ask-Ubuntu circumstances and not off-topic.

Comment: I find the question pertinent and here is the answer: https://ridicurious.com/2018/10/18/2-ways-to-copy-files-from-windows-10-to-windows-sub-system-for-linux/

Comment: A question about development environments should be on-topic. Which SO rule do I need to address?

Comment: @LeeGoddard WSL is not just for development though. Following your reasoning, because I develop on Windows and MacOS, all Windows and MacOS questions would be on-topic as well. They are not.

Comment: @MarkRotteveel I don't see how that addresses my question.

Comment: @LeeGoddard This question is not development related, but simply an OS question, and as such is not about tools primarily used for development, and thus is off-topic (point 6 on https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic).

Comment: Given the amount of reach and help this question has given members of the community, regardless of what rules you point this... Wasn't that the intent of stackoverflow to begin with? To help others and to help each other learn programming, operating systems, etc.. You guys can do w/e you want, I'm just glad that my question was able to help quite a few people who were struggling with the same issue as I. All the best o/

Comment: Those who have read the question and find themselves in these circumstances understand that this is a question regarding Windows and using the Windows Subsystem for Linux (WSL) tool that is available in that OS. WSL is available for development purposes more than running Linux stuff on Windows.

Answer (score 364, accepted):

You should be able to access your windows system under the `/mnt` directory. For example inside of bash, use this to get to your pictures directory:

```bash
cd /mnt/c/Users/<windows.username>/Pictures
```

Comment: I believe you misunderstood. I have a JPG on my desktop, i copied it with the UI into the bash subsystem directory. I am trying to understand why bash can't see those pictures when they are in it's home directory.

This is basic cygwin behavior, drag and drop or copy paste files over without relying on linux commands to do the job.

Comment: you are probably in the wrong folder.

Comment: The Linux subsystem doesn't have the same design criteria as Cygwin.  You can't necessarily expect them to behave similarly.

Comment: it worked for me, though `ubuntu.username` is not necessary the username for windows.. al least it is not the case for me ;)

Comment: @JordanGS it may be a permissions issue

Comment: Note that in wsl2, this will lead to slow access

Comment: Typing `explorer.exe .` inside WSL opens up a Windows Explorer window showing your current WSL folder. Drag any file into that window!

Answer (score 76):

You should only access Linux files system (those located in lxss folder) from *inside WSL*; **DO NOT** create/modify any files in lxss folder in Windows - it's dangerous and WSL will not see these files.

Files can be shared between WSL and Windows, though; put the file outside of lxss folder. You can access them via drvFS (`/mnt`) such as `/mnt/c/Users/yourusername/files` within WSL. These files stay synced between WSL and Windows.

For details and why, see:
https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/commandline/2016/11/17/do-not-change-linux-files-using-windows-apps-and-tools/

Comment: See also [WSL File System Support](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/wsl/2016/06/15/wsl-file-system-support/).

Comment: In  [WSL File System Support](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/wsl/2016/06/15/wsl-file-system-support/) it describes why the behavior is happening: the file "translation" is done in the lsxx subsystem (on the linux side) only.

Comment: On a linux VM, I can use SFTP to transfer files, what do I use to transfer file PROPERLY from Window to linux subsystem ? this does not provide a solution.

Comment: @AmbroiseRabier In latest version of WSL, use SFTP, tar file, or integrated 9p protocol.