# Windows 10 Bash Issue

Tags: windows, bash

I have installed Bash on my Windows 10 computer. I have an issue. I can only make it recognize the files I create in the bash terminal. If I make a file in notepad++ with a .cpp or .c extension it won't recognize it. It's easier to edit files in notepad++ so I was wanting to know if there was a way I can make it recognize files outside of the ones made using the terminal.

Comment: Possible duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/q/42586120/886887

Comment: Yes, I saw that before I posted. The question is similar but doesn't explain why it wouldn't show up or a solution mnt isn't working.

Comment: If you mean that you aren't able to see files on `/mnt/c` then that is a different question, but you need to edit your question to make that clear.  You could also be more specific about what you mean by "recognize", do the files not appear in directory listings?  Where exactly are the files?