# Move file from windows 10 to ubuntu folder using gitbash terminal

Tags: python, linux, windows, image, ubuntu

I am using Ubuntu on windows 10 and I need to move a file from a windows folder into ubuntu folder using the git bash terminal.

How would I do this?

Comment: You are probably want to use `scp` to copy a file to another host.

Comment: Where are you running ubuntu? On the same machine? Like this: https://ubuntu.com/tutorials/tutorial-ubuntu-on-windows#1-overview
Or are you running two seperate machines? Are you able to access the windows folder with git bash?

Comment: im running on the same machine

Answer (score 4):

Actually, I'm not sure why, but you cannot move a folder from windows to WSL. It causes permission denied error on removing process (moving consists of copy & remove). But you can copy it instead using BASH.

Steps :

1. Put your folder in User Directory (ex. `C://Users/Admin/`)
2. Open your ubuntu terminal
3. Copy it recursively. Ex :

```sh
cp -r /mnt/c/Users/Admin/AFolder ./FolderInWSL/
```

Answer (score 1):

You should move the file from within Ubuntu, not the other way around, because if you copy from Windows to Ubuntu, you will run into permissions errors.

Sources:

- https://askubuntu.com/questions/1049895/permission-error-copying-files-into-ubuntu-on-windows-with-windows-copy-paste
- https://askubuntu.com/questions/759880/where-is-the-ubuntu-file-system-root-directory-in-windows-subsystem-for-linux-an

See this for the solution: [Copy Files from Windows to the Ubuntu Subsystem](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42586120/copy-files-from-windows-to-the-ubuntu-subsystem)

So the moving would be *from within the ubuntu shell* something like:

```
mv /mnt/<windows_drive_letter>/<path>/<filename> .
```

Comment: Thank you so much, I am using ubuntu on windows 10